# Bounded context entity schema changes in microservices

Tags: domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

I am trying to understand Bounded Context that holds it's own copy of Entity in a sense.
As an example, given that I have a root entity `Supplier` and another entity `Client` and both have `User` entity. In my understanding, for my `Sales` context which requires `Client` and `Purchase` context which requires `Supplier`, both of them will have their own entities and as for `User` entity, will be duplicated in both context.

My question is, if there is a change in the structure of the `User` entity, how do I handle the changes? Do I need to go to each **context** that has `User` entity and change each of them? I'm fine with **data** duplication, but **code** duplication kindda breaks the **DRY** principles no?

In monolithic is quite simple as the dependencies from both `Supplier` and `Client` pointing to that same `User`. But for bounded context, since each **context** will own it's own copy of `User` context. Any changes in the schema that is used across the **context** will have to be managed together. Is this the right approach or am I missing something?

Edit:
To make things more clear, I'm including a very simple diagram to show what I meant and hope can help in making things much easier to understand.

For monolithic approach:
[image: monolithic]

Since the `User` is **shared** by both `Supplier` and `Client`. Changes made in `User` will reflect on both sides. Adhering to **Single Responsibility** and **DRY** principle.

For bounded context:
[image]

Since `User` is **copied** on both `Supplier` and `Client`. If any requirement changes in term of schema and structure of `User` data. I will have to update on both sides **if** the data is required by **both**.
Example of schema changes would be from a combined **first and last name** to separated **first name** and **last name**.

Answer (score 2):

Within a bounded context, an entity should only contain the data that the context needs in order to meet its obligations: a `User` in the purchasing context isn't necessarily the same as a `User` in the sales context, and they can evolve independently.  For instance, if you have a bounded context that owns (is responsible for updating) user profiles, in other contexts it may be that all that's needed is to know that a user with a given ID exists.

If you're also following the hexagonal/ports-and-adapters approach, it's possible that the adapter (or anti-corruption-layer/read-side, depending on your perspective) responsible for translating updates in one context into the model of another context might need to change (though things like tolerant readers (e.g. a JSON deserializer which expects a string for key `fullName` accepting `{"fullName": "Charlie Bucket", "age": 10}` and ignoring the extra `age` key because its model doesn't care about age) can often reduce the need for this).  Even then, the point of the adapter is to immunize the domain model of a context from changes in the model in other contexts, so that what needs to get updated is well-contained.

Comment: that's the same understanding that I have, but the issue I'm facing is that the data that is required in both context have a change of schema. For instance, the `User` has a prop `contactNo` where is required in both `Sales` and `Purchase`. Now the schema has to change to separate country code and the number. Now I have to change on both and other boundry that requires that data across, is that unavoidable?

Comment: If the schemas inside `Sales` and `Purchase` work fine without separating out the country code, why change them?  If you're getting `{ "countryCode": "1", "phoneNr": "5088675309" }`, why can't it just be changed at the boundary to `"+15088675309"`?

Comment: So i get it, it's not necessary to change the data structure for BC unless it is required for the use case of the BC itself. What I need to do is to add a handler to handle different event data structure instead?

Answer (score 1):

A `User` would be an entity (or aggregate root) in the `Identity and Access Management` bounded context.  In downstream systems/BCs any representation of a `User` would be a value object.

One way around this is to simply *not* store any additional data for the `User` in the downstream bounded contexts; instead only storing the Id of the `User`.  Is there really any `User` data that you cannot do without?  That is the simplest solution and your front-end, or any part of your solution, could retrieve any additional data from the IAM BC via some form of integration mechanism such as a REST interface.

If, however, there *is* additional data that you need a downstream BC would probably need to rely on a pub/sub mechanism to be informed of any changes to the `User`.  This message would probably still only send off an Id and the downstream BC can retrieve the relevant additional data and update the local value object.  Of course, it never hurts to have some mechanism where the update to the data can be forced :)

Not having any data in a downstream BC protects the downstream system from upstream schema changes.  In the case where there really is data that you need to store the integration mechanism (anti-corruption layer) could protect your downstream BC from upstream schema changes.